# Did we see when The Flash learned about Superman?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, supergirl

Some spoilers about the latest episode of The Flash (Duet - season 3 episode 17).

I believe it was during the last song that Barry made a clear reference to Superman. Has Kara ever mentioned her cousin to Barry on either Supergirl or The Flash, or is this just one of those things we are just to assume that they talked about off-camera?

Comment: The Flash and Cisco spent some time in Kara's dimension that last time they crossed over.  Given the amount of publicity Superman gets, it's reasonable to assume they got some information about him.

Remember that just because the episodes only last 45 minutes, doesn't mean the characters don't spend hours or even days together.  There's a lot that happens off-screen that we don't see.

Comment: I believe Barry's lyrics in the song were "super friend", actually.

Comment: @TylerH He explicitly talks about Superman: "[BARRY]: When you need a compliment / I can rattle off a dozen / For instance, I have to say I'm not impressed / By your more famous cousin."  "(Spoken) [KARA] Thank you! No one ever says that!" "[BARRY] Oh, he's all like 'Oh, I'm Superman!'" "[KARA] That's a really good impression"

Comment: @PaulL I must be thinking of the earlier song, or perhaps earlier in the same song. I'll have to go back and watch that episode again.

Comment: @TylerH Same song, just different parts.  "Super Friend" was repeated over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On screen, Kara never mentions Superman by name, but in the *Legends of Tomorrow* episode *Invasion* (season 2, episode 7), she mentions her "cousin" to the group, and the fact that they're extremely powerful.

It stands to reason that she would have explained further, especially with all the excitement over meeting not just an alien, but one from an alternate universe.

From [the transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Invasion!_(DC%27s_Legends_of_Tomorrow))

> But, back on my Earth, it's just me and my cousin. Between the two of us, we're more powerful than...